# Mount BTRFS on Android (usb OTG)

Tags: android, btrfs, usb-otg

I am using btrFS as a filesystem for my external harddrive.

I'd like to use it under Android. Is there any painless way to do so?

Comment: Please, read this - http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/29572/will-android-read-any-other-non-fat-file-system-on-sd-card - It seems that brtfs and also, i did check the Play Store to find some app that would make this happen and didn´t found.

Comment: Is this a rooted Android? What version?

Comment: No, it's not rooted. It's Android 4.4.2.

Comment: Nearly impossible to do this without rooting..  However if you rooted things will be a lot more simpler.

Answer (score 1):

You can try to build and flash a custom kernel for your device. Just enable btrfs in the configuration. (You can build btrfs as a module and try to insert it in your device, but the kernel would possibly refuse to insert a module not built together with it.)

You may also need to build a modified version of vold if you want to mount btrfs volumns automatically.

However, If your kernel version is really old, mounting btrfs could be unstable and ruin your data.